# How to start developing a Web Api 2.2 project with Asp.Net MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I have an MVC5 Project and Non browser project. We just upgraded from MVC4 to MVC5 and included a Web Api project. Now we want to make use of Web Api 2.2 and   we have created some HTTP methods which works fine in our Api Project. My question is how should I start with Authentication/Authorization.Do I need to create an Authentication Filter class inheriting from ActionFilterAttribute. [I referred this link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters) How should I begin with . I am confused how should I use the IPrincipal and set the Identity. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: what problem are you facing with this ?

Comment: @FrebinFrancis thanks for ur response. I wnt to knw where should I start from Authenticating a user and then creating a token. Is it mandatory to have Authentication filter or Normally can I validate a user.

Comment: it is a common and standard approach to use authentication filter in web api so better start with the authentication filter (if your are working with MVC 5)

Comment: @FrebinFrancis then how should I begin with. Say once I have done with Custom Authorize class and decorated controllers with the same and now a user logins now what should I  do further. As per the link  there is CustomAuthentication Filter. Is it mandatory if not then how should I set the Identity? and if yes plz give a link or any help I am struggling at this point.

Comment: this might be a useful link http://bitoftech.net/2015/02/16/implement-oauth-json-web-tokens-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api-and-identity-2/

Comment: The links bellow helped me about Authorization/Authentication in Web Api: http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/. I hope it helps you.

Comment: @CiscoCabe but where and how to set the IPrincipal object.....

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry I thought you want to develop token based authentication so I put that link, I understand you want to develop base authentication. Anyway, IPrincipal interfaz is into System.Security.Principal namespace.

Comment: @CiscoCabe well thanks for your concern. Could plz tell me wht should I do once a user logins. Do I need to create an authentication filter or how should I start with.If you plz give a short description for the same will be very helpful for a beginner like me. Thanks

Comment: I don't know what kind of web application you are doing but I suggest you use token based authentication. Develop this kind of security is easy because .net template does almost everything for you. You can follow both this link http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api and http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

Answer (score 0):

The new version is called **ASP.NET Identity framework** - There are some changes from the **ASP.NET Membership** in the table structure and everything works through Entity Framework, the tables are created using code first but you can also create it using a script, for example: [identity.codeplex.com](http://identity.codeplex.com/) and [SQL-script-for-creating-an-ASP-NET-Identity-Databa](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/677279/SQL-script-for-creating-an-ASP-NET-Identity-Databa) or you run the solution using a valid SQL connection string and the tables will be created on first run (code first is doing that - it's built in the entity framework)...

When you create a sample MVC project you will have the basic functionality

Also, check out these resources:

- http://johnatten.com/2013/11/11/extending-identity-accounts-and-implementing-role-based-authentication-in-asp-net-mvc-5/
- http://johnatten.com/2014/06/22/asp-net-identity-2-0-customizing-users-and-roles/
- http://johnatten.com/2014/10/26/asp-net-web-api-and-identity-2-0-customizing-identity-models-and-implementing-role-based-authorization/
- http://johnatten.com/2014/02/13/asp-net-mvc-5-identity-extending-and-modifying-roles
- http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/aspnet-identity-recommended-resources
- http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started
- http://johnatten.com/2014/04/20/asp-net-mvc-and-identity-2-0-understanding-the-basics/

Also, the new table primary keys are changed so the code can run on any type of database, so it's a 128 string key by default (just between us - the database optimization could be made a little better than this) if you're looking for some trouble, check out these links as well:

- https://github.com/TypecastException/AspNet-Identity-2-With-Integer-Keys
- https://github.com/TypecastException/AspNet-Identity-2-Extensible-Project-Template